# Qt: how to apply a 2-step key shortcut to action

Tags: qt, user-interface

I know how to apply a keyboard shortcut to an action. And in some software such as Visual Studio there are shortcuts that do the job in more than one step (such as `Ctrl+K`,`Ctrl+C` to comment the code).

Another example of that in Sublime Text:

[image]

I wonder whether or not it is possible to implement in Qt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
action->setShortcut("Ctrl+K,Ctrl+C");
```

`QKeySequence` may be implicitly created from `QString`.
Due to [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qkeysequence.html#QKeySequence-1):

> Up to four key codes may be entered by separating them with commas, e.g. "Alt+X,Ctrl+S,Q".

MOC generates almost same code when you create shortcut for a `QAction` via Qt Designer. But it makes it slightly different:

```
action->setShortcut(QApplication::translate("MainWindow", "Ctrl+K, Ctrl+C", 0));
```

but it's actually same thing.

Comment: Thanks, I tried your method and it works. It is surely the most simple but useful way, I think.

Answer (score 2):

You can create it by using the multiple arguments constructor for [QKeySequence](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qkeysequence.html).

like this:

```
auto ac = new QAction(this);
ac->setShortcut(QKeySequence(Qt::CTRL + Qt::Key_K, Qt::CTRL + Qt::Key_C));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [eventFilter](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/eventsandfilters.html) to get mouse & keyboard events.

I use boolean to get first and second key, Ctrl + K then C.

I made you a sample code it's working.

.cpp file:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    firstKey = false;
    secondKey = false;
    this->installEventFilter(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

bool MainWindow::eventFilter(QObject *object, QEvent *event)
{
    if (object == this &&event->type() == QEvent::KeyPress)
    {
        QKeyEvent *keyEvent = static_cast<QKeyEvent *>(event);
        if ((keyEvent->key() == Qt::Key_Control))
        {
            firstKey = true;
            return true;
        }
        else if ((keyEvent->key() == Qt::Key_K))
        {
            secondKey = true;
            return true;
        }
        else if ((keyEvent->key() == Qt::Key_C))
        {
            if(firstKey && secondKey)
            {
                firstKey = false;
                secondKey = false;
                QMessageBox::information(this, "", "Ctrl + k + c");
            }
            return true;
        }
        else
            return false;
    }
    else
        return false;
}

void MainWindow::keyReleaseEvent(QKeyEvent *e)
{
    if (e->type() == QEvent::KeyRelease)
    {
        QKeyEvent *keyEvent = static_cast<QKeyEvent *>(e);
        if ((keyEvent->key() == Qt::Key_Control))
        {
            firstKey = false;
        }
    }
}
```

.h file:

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QMessageBox>
#include <QKeyEvent>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

    bool firstKey;
    bool secondKey;
    bool eventFilter(QObject *object, QEvent *event);
    void keyReleaseEvent(QKeyEvent *e);

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

Comment: I think your implementation has bugs. You have to distinguish between single key press and key combination press. With the current implementation I can trigger message box with pressing and releasing `Ctrl` then `K` then `C` keys separately. Or alternatively `K`, `Ctrl` and then `C` which is incorrect. The idea is that both `Ctrl` and `C` keys should be pressed simultaneously to trigger the action. Am I wrong?

Comment: @vahancho You're right. i update my answer. now it's need to press Ctrl and hold it to get MsgBox.

Comment: Hm, but you could achieve the same much easier without writing so much code to handle `Ctrl` key. What if you use `QKeyEvent::modifiers()` to check, whether `Ctrl` is pressed? Something like: `if (keyEvent->key() == Qt::Key_K && keyEvent->modifiers() == Qt::ControlModifier)...`

Comment: @vahancho yes it could be implement with less code.But please read [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qkeyevent.html#modifiers). --- Warning: This function cannot always be trusted. The user can confuse it by pressing both Shift keys simultaneously and releasing one of them.